# Proving an Inequality using a Different Method

Tags: inequality

Is there another way to prove that: If $a,b\geq 0$ and $x,y>0$

$$\frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{y} \ge \frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y}$$

using a different method than clearing denominators and reducing to $(ay-bx)^2 \ge 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is Titu's lemma, that is equivalent to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$ (x+y)\left(\frac{a^2}{x}+\frac{b^2}{y}\right)\geq(a+b)^2. $$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{y} 
\ge \frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y}
$

Let
$u = a^2/x$
and
$v = b^2/y$,
so
$a = \sqrt{ux}$
and
$b = \sqrt{vy}$.

The inequality then becomes
$u+v
\ge \frac{(\sqrt{ux}+\sqrt{vy})^2}{x+y}
= \frac{ux+vy+2\sqrt{uxvy}}{x+y}
$
or
$ux+uy+vx+vy
\ge ux+vy+2\sqrt{uxvy}
$
or
$uy+vx
\ge 2\sqrt{uxvy}
$
or
$(\sqrt{uy}-\sqrt{vx})^2
\ge 0
$.

I don't know different this really is,
since it does clear the denominator,
but it looks different.

Anyway,
most inequalities usually 
are equivalent to
$(something)^2 \ge 0
$.

Answer (score 1):

One method of solving any inequality is to determine points where the associated **equality** is true or where the functions involved are not continuous.  That is because, as long as $a$ and $b$ are continuous, we can only go from "$a> b$" to "$a< b$", or vice-versa, by going through "$a= b$".

However here, the simplest way to solve the equality is by "clearing denominators" so apparently you would not consider that a "different" way.

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts need heavy editing.